# Replace item in association list in elisp

Tags: lisp, elisp, associative-array

I have an alist in emacs lisp like:

```
(setq a1
 '((:k1 . 1)
   (:k2 . 2)
   (:k3 . 3)))
```

and i want to change value of :k1 to 10, like `(:k1 . 10)`. How do i do that?

I tried `(setf (assoc :k1 a1) '(:k1 . 10))` - it didn't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With alists, you usually add a new cons in front of the old one to "shadow" the old value, like so:

```
(add-to-list 'a1 '(:k1 10))
```

After you do this `(assoc :k1 a1)` will return 10.

If you want to "undo" your change so `assoc` again returns your old value, use this code:

```
(setq a1 (delq (assoc :k1 a1) a1))
```

This will remove the **FIRST** match for `:k1` from `a1`.

Answer (score 17):

As of Emacs 25.1, `alist-get` is a place form so you can do:

```
(setf (alist-get :k1 a1) 10)
```

Answer (score 8):

The `setf` macro doesn't know about `assoc`, but you could still use that approach in a slightly more manual fashion:

```el
(let ((item (assoc :k1 a1)))
  (setf (car item) :k1)
  (setf (cdr item) 10))
```

and if all that is required is to set the cdr for the given car (rather than replacing both), then we can simplify this to just:

```el
(setf (cdr (assoc :k1 a1)) 10)
```

Comment: It's probably not necessary to set the car to :k1, as that's already the value. As a general rule, it's probably better to push new values onto assoc lists than modify them, but it all depends on why one is trying to set a new value.

Comment: Agreed, but as I was adapting the code in the question, and that did set the car, I included that here as well. Of course if setting the car is not desired, then the code can be simplified, so I'll add that alternative.

Answer (score 7):

This shorter and simpler version works in Emacs Lisp (MAC Lisp) for me:

```
(setcdr (assoc :k1 a1) 10)
```

or, if you happen to be using Common Lisp:

```
(rplacd (assoc :k1 a1) 10)
```

(Note that setcdr and rplacd may behave slightly different when it comes to which value they return.)

Answer (score 1):

What about `assq-delete-all`:

```
(setq sql-product-alist
      (cons '(ms-tsql :server ....)
            (assq-delete-all 'ms-tsql sql-product-alist)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function based on gavenkoa's suggestion -

```
(defun alist-set (alist-symbol key value)
  "Set KEY to VALUE in alist ALIST-SYMBOL."
  (set alist-symbol
        (cons (list key value) 
              (assq-delete-all key (eval alist-symbol)))))
```

usage -

```
(let ((foo '((a 1) (b 2))))
  (alist-set 'foo 'a 3)
  foo) ; => ((a 3) (b 2))
```